# Can rails have multiple relations to a model in the same model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a `similar_merchants` model where I store merchants which are similar to other merchants.

Here are the fields in the table:

```
merchant_id
related_merchant_id
```

**How do I write the relations in this case?**

Here is what I have right now:

```
class SimilarMerchant < ActiveRecord::Base

  # relationships
  belongs_to :merchant
  belongs_to :merchant, :foreign_key => 'related_merchant_id'

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class SimilarMerchant < ActiveRecord::Base

  # relationships
  belongs_to :merchant
  belongs_to :related_merchant, :foreign_key => 'related_merchant_id', :class_name => "Merchant"

end
```

This will do. You can call like this:

```
similar_merchant = SimilarMerchant.find(1)
similar_merchant.merchant
=> # Merchant record
similar_merchant.related_merchant
=> # Related Merchant record
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough:

```
class SimilarMerchant < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key 'merchant_id'


  belongs_to :merchant, :foreign_key => 'related_merchant_id'

end
```

As per the documentation, the foreign_key is guesssed to be the name of the association plus an '_id' suffix.

Comment: but there will be several entries of the same merchant_id.

Comment: @Jacob Is `merchant_id` the primary key of the SimilarMErchant model? If it's not, then why are there both `merchant_id` and `related_merchant_id` in the model?